# Bash - unzip: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, sh

I am trying to unzip the file in particular folder and i am getting a "unzip command not found" error.

I am using Cygdrive to run my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in ./"$WORKING"/*
do
    unzip '*'
done
```

Comment: @LtWorf - Can you please guide me how to install Unzip into my cygwin

Comment: @qwwqwwq - what do you mean by terminal?

Comment: Run `setup.exe` (the same program you used to install Cygwin in the first place) to install `unzip`. I'm not sure what the package name is, but it shouldn't be hard to find.

Comment: @KeithThompson - thank you let me try this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package is [`unzip`](https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/unzip/)

```
setup -nqP unzip
```

or use the GUI.

[in the wild](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/de9a1a1/.packages#L5)

Comment: 404 not found on the unzip link

Comment: $ setup -nqP unzip
-bash: setup: command not found